# Magento 1.9.2.2 - I can't seem to open anything on admin panel

Tags: php, magento

I have just installed Magento 1.9.2.2 on IIS7 today, and there are two messages on my admin panel.

1. Latest Message: Reminder: Change Magento`s default phone numbers and callouts before site launch
2. One or more of the Indexes are not up to date: Product Attributes, Product Prices, Catalog URL Rewrites, Product Flat Data, Category Flat Data, Category Products, Catalog Search Index, Stock Status, Tag Aggregation Data. Click here to go to Index Management and rebuild required indexes.

And whenever I click anything on the admin panel, it will show this error:

There has been an error processing your request

Could not determine temp directory, please specify a cache_dir manually

```
#0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\magento\lib\Zend\Cache\Backend.php(217): Zend_Cache::throwException('Could not deter...')
#1 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\magento\lib\Zend\Cache\Backend\File.php(130): Zend_Cache_Backend->getTmpDir()
#2 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\magento\lib\Zend\Cache.php(153): Zend_Cache_Backend_File->__construct(Array)
#3 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\magento\lib\Zend\Cache.php(94): Zend_Cache::_makeBackend('File', Array, false, false)
#4 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\magento\lib\Zend\Locale\Data.php(328): Zend_Cache::factory('Core', 'File', Array, Array)
#5 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Html\Calendar.php(42): Zend_Locale_Data::getList('en_US', 'days')
#6 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Html_Calendar->_toHtml()
#7 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#8 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('calendar', true)
#9 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\magento\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\page\head.phtml(59): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('calendar')
#10 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(241): include('C:\\inetpub\\wwwr...')
#11 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml\\defau...')
#12 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#13 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#14 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#15 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('head', true)
#16 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\magento\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\page.phtml(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('head')
#17 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(241): include('C:\\inetpub\\wwwr...')
#18 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml\\defau...')
#19 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#20 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#21 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#22 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#23 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#24 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\controllers\System\ConfigController.php(119): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#25 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_System_ConfigController->editAction()
#26 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
#27 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#28 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#29 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\magento\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#30 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\magento\index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#31 {main}
```

I really don't know what is going on here, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

On a LAMP environment(linux/apache/mysql/php) there is the /tmp directory that is used as tmp by most applications. I am not sure how windows handles this but i do believe it also has a tmp directory. I am not that familiar with PHP on windows/IIS environments but maybe one of these links can help you set up a TMP directory for php:

[Changing PHP Temp Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26280299/changing-php-temp-directory)

http://forums.iis.net/t/1179270.aspx?Temp+Directory+is+still+set+to+C+WINDOWS+TEMP+even+after+I+change+it+in+PHP+ini

And following in that: 
http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/install-and-configure-php

Comment: hi @nenne I don't know is this the one you are talking about or not?

Comment: protected $_options = array(
        'cache_dir' =>  "var/tmp/",
        'file_locking' => true,
    );

Comment: after I edited the 'cache_dir' => null to 'cache_dir' =>"var/tmp/" , I also create the tmp directory in var folder. But it seems like it doesn't help at all.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Fixed it by adding a tmp folder in var/ because it didn't exist. If var/cache doesn't exist too, then just create it.

I changed YOURWEBSITE/lib/zend/cache/backend/file.php under protected ... 'cache_dir' => null to 'cache_dir' =>"var/tmp/"

It worked. I deleted everything in Cache too before.